# Nested SQL query using CASE statements

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I write just one SQL query to get the same result by perform these two queries (steps):

First Step:

```
SELECT old_id, new_id FROM history WHERE flag = 1;
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+
| old_id | new_id |
+--------+--------+
|     11 |     22 |
|     33 |     44 |
|     55 |     66 |
+--------+--------+
```

And then, using previous results, execute this query:

```
UPDATE other_tabla SET somefk_id = CASE somefk_id
    WHEN 11 THEN 22
    WHEN 33 THEN 44
    WHEN 55 THEN 66
END WHERE somefk_id IN (11,33,55)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're describing:

```
UPDATE `other_tablea`
JOIN `history` ON history.old_id = other_tablea.somefk_id AND history.flag = 1
SET other_tablea.somefk_id = history.new_id
```

Answer (score 1):

A subquery would appear to do the trick:

```
update  other_tabla
set     somefk_id = coalesce((
            select  new_id 
            from    history 
            where   flag = 1 
                    and old_id = other_tabla.somefk_id
        ), other_tabla.somefk_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `case`

```
update
  other_table, history 
set
  other_table.somefk_id=history.new_id
where 
  other_table.somefk_id=history.old_id and history.flag=1;
```

Comment: +1 Add `and flag = 1` at the end, and this works. Nice short version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary table to store de results of the first Query and then resuse the data in the second query.

```
SELECT old_id, new_id 
INTO #tmpTable1
FROM history 
WHERE flag = 1;

UPDATE other_tabla SET somefk_id = t.new.id
FROM other_tabla as o
INNER JOIN #tmpTable1 t ON o.somefk_id=t.old_id

DROP TABLE #tmpTable1
```

Comment: As you can see in other answers is not necessary a temporal table. Also, I asked for ONLY 1 query statement. Your answer use 3, thanks anyway.